# dialog activity control

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

What I want to do: When the application starts it reads an email address from a database. If the email address is NOT set, it starts another dialog activity for adding the email address.

If the user doesn't add the email, he cannot close that dialog activity, so clicking on close button doesn't close the dialog activity.

The problem that I have is that if the user clicks the back button, the dialog activity closes and the main activity starts without email address set. What I want to do is if the user clicks the back button in this case, to close the application.

I have to mention that I'm using the same dialog activity when I want to edit the email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onBackPressed`,  there check whether user has inserted any email address. If not just return without calling super.onBackPressed().

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(yourEmailEditText.getText() == null 
       || yourEmailEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
          return
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in android called dialog Activity. Either it is a dialog (AlertDialog, ProgressDialog), or an activity. `onBackPressed` should be overridden in your `Activity` class. You just need to make sure you get the reference to the `EditText`, in which email is entered, in `onBackPressed`

Comment: OK. This works nice. What I meant by "dialog activity" is the activity that is set in the manifest to open as a dialog :)

Comment: My solution works.. But you just consider @rgrocha answer too. That might work too..

Comment: OK. One more question: How to set the activity to not close when clicked outside it? I know how to do it on custom dialog, but I don't know how to do it in this case

Comment: Your activity is not fullscreen?

Comment: No. It opens like a dialog defined in the manifest android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"

Comment: don't have much knowledge about that.. Sorry

Comment: Found it. Just have to put this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false); in the activity that opens like dialog. Nothing else :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Overriding the onBackPressed() method and do nothing into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Dialog as non-cancellable in one of the constructors second parameters:

```
 Dialog(Context context, boolean cancelable, DialogInterface.OnCancelListener cancelListener)
```

Also take into the account what happens if the user by-pass the dialog by any means (any button by hardware, etc). You could simply interprete this as the user wants to exit the application.